# How can I display an HTML file as a web page?

Tags: java, html, swing, web, jeditorpane

My code reads an HTML file and I want to show it in new frame as a web page.
But I don't know - how can I do this?

This is my code:

```
public class EditorPaneLoad extends JFrame{ 

public EditorPaneLoad() throws Exception{

    FileReader reader = new FileReader("a.html");
    JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
    JTextPane editor = new JTextPane();
    editor.setContentType( "text/html" );
    editor.setEditable( false );
    editor.read(reader, null);
    //System.out.println(editor.getText());
    //System.out.println("\n------------\n");
    Document doc = editor.getDocument();
    // System.out.println(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( editor );
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(300, 200) );
    getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
{
    EditorPaneLoad frame = new EditorPaneLoad();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  The current code should 'show HTML as HTML formatted'.  What more do you expect?

Comment: i want to make it in Design type GUI in netbeans with button,but i can't

Comment: Do you mean you want to make an HTML editor?  Note that `JEditorPane` was never intended to display 'real world HTML'. It only supports HTML **3.2** and limited very styles. No applets, flash or JavaScript are supported at all. It certainly would not be useful for designing 'real world HTML'!

Comment: no,i have a HTML file,and i want to Display it as a web-page,as a real page in Browser,but it just a HTML code,and i want it to read a HTML file and open a new Frame and in this frame show the web version of that HTML code,show me a example Code in Netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// opens "a.html" in the default browser..
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("a.html"));
```

See [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) for details.

Comment: @user3188155 This would run the default browser showing the specific html. It is not the same as showing the html through **your desktop application**.

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas  But note it will show it *"as a web-page,as a real page in Browser"* as per the OP's 2nd comment.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, you want to render HTML through a desktop window of your application.

Perhaps [flying saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) would help you. An alternative, [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) would be rendered using javafx but it would only support HTML 4.

Hope I helped!

Comment: this is exactly what i want :)

Comment: i don't have a Browser,i just have File.HTML,i read it,and i want to show this Content as Real web page,but just in a new Frame