# Saving the file generated in Applet

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, browser, applet

In servlet  I can write

```
  response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

So that the file is available to download by user.

But how would I go about it where I'm generating a file  in side a applet ?

It is possible if  user give a path to save then i can do

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pathtoSave);
```

But I don't want to prompt user for a path.

Any help regarding this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't want to prompt user for a path.

Put it in a sub-directory of `user.home`<sup>1</sup>.  Then after it is saved I strongly advise to display it to the user, using the `Desktop`<sup>2</sup> API (so they can know where it is).

1. As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8251008/418556) to "Java Applet Download File".
2. As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21101645/418556) to "How can I display an HTML file as a web page?".

Comment: No worries, Sury.  (And if you did not get my subtle meaning, my name is not 'Andy', just like I guess yours is not 'Sury'.)